# Implement atomic transactions over multiple AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I want to implement atomic transactions over multiple AWS resources -- e.g. uploading an object to S3 and adding a record to a DynamoDB table. Both should happen in lockstep -- or not at all. If one of the operations fails, the other should be rolled back. I understand I can implement it myself, but I was wondering if there is an existing library that does it.

One of the challenges while implementing this is expiry of temporary credentials. What if credentials expire after one of the operations was performed?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot use transaction over these services (they are not enrolled in any distributes tx manager). However you may try to use compensation approach (when using resource roles, e. g. from ec2 or lambda, credentials should get refreshed)

Comment: I don't meant a transaction in a literal sense. I want something that will ensure that either all operations succeed, or none at all -- i.e. if any one of them fails, all others are rolled back. I *can* (and probably will) implement something myself, but I am wondering if someone has attempted something similar. Even if the code is not publicly available, any suggestions/tips are welcome.

Comment: you can have a look at Cloudformation.. if some resource fails to provision, it will attempt to deprovision resource which are already created

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are hard! Especially in a distributed system. Transactions are also slow.

If there is any way to redesign your system to not require transactional semantics, I strongly encourage you to try.

If you really need transactions, involving multiple AWS resources, across different services.. you sort of have to roll your own. You can leverage a distributed data store that supports atomic operations and build on top of that.

It won’t be easy.